# Creating an RSS from Scratch

Tags: feeds

I'm converting a site to D7 that does not currently have an RSS feed. I'm trying to find a way to create something that will help me avoid having to manually move over each and every page, but I'm coming up empty.

I thought of wanted to try to generate a feed, with the goal being to use the Feeds module to import the feed as pages, but I've not found anything to do that sufficiently.

Right now all the pages are stand-alone pages meaning that none of them are stored in a database, but it's all written up in PHP & HTML and it's a bit of a mess. So I'm having to work with the raw pages. That's why I thought creating a feed would be the way to go.

If I could get the existing pages in to a CSV or XML file I could work with them a little easier, but there are numerous pages and it would take forever to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [Goutte](http://drupal.org/project/goutte). I thought there was a similar Migrate module + Goutte frontend out there ... but can't find it.